# How to bulk sell 10000 NFTs to OpenSea's Ethereum network programmatically?

Tags: metamask, nft, opensea

I have 10,000 NFTs generated by https://the-nft-generator.com How can I bulk upload the 10,000 NFTs to OpenSea's Ethereum network programmatically? Doing so via selenium & chromium driver is unreliable. Any alternative?

I know OpenSea doesn't have a public API you can use to bulk upload NFTs to ETH network, and it seems the only option is either making a regular contract (which wouldn't be lazy-minted) or using selenium or playwright to upload to Ethereum network. Any ideas?

p.s. I'm using MetaMask wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use this tool: [OpenSea Workshop](https://openseaworkshop.com). I am its creator. The tool uses the OpenSea API in an optimized way to reach a speed of 1k NFTs per hour; and uses MetaMask as a wallet.

The prices are relatively accessible, at least cheaper than most smart contracts.

If you have any other questions, don't hesitate.